# Get all events from Google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there any possible way to get all events from google analytics? I mean something like `ga.getAllEvents()` that will return an object with event categories and total ammount of events.

Any help is appreciated:)

Comment: Are you talking about events for the currently user that they've sent since the page was loaded? Or are you talking about all events, like you'd see in the events reports on the Google Analytics website?

Comment: I mean retrieve an object like in report, yes.

Answer (score -1):

The analytics.js library (which creates the `ga` object you reference in your question) if for collecting interaction data from your users. It's not for reporting on that data.

After all, the analytics.js library is running in the browsers of **other people** visiting **your** website. Would you really want those other people to be able to see the event data from your website?

To programmatically report on your data in code, you need to use one of the reporting APIs. Have a look at this guide to see which reporting API is best for your situation:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core